# firebase-admin auth().listProviderConfig() returns no providers

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Hoping someone can help... my firebase function's call to `listProviderConfig()` always returns *nothing* (`providerConfigs: []`) even tho I have 3 providers configured:

```
export const providers = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const { type = 'oidc' } = req.query as { type?: 'oidc' | 'saml' };

  admin
    .auth()
    .listProviderConfigs({ type })
    .then(results => res.json(results))
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json(error));
});
```

I've already verified that:

- Google Identity Platform is enabled for this project
- the providers are enabled (and `signInWithPopup()` etc. from the client works fine)
- same empty result for `oidc` and `saml` queries

**Any help HUGELY appreciated!**

---

A few things to note:

- For debugging, this is an `https.onRequest()` function - my ultimate use case will be as `https.onCall()` - any difference?
- I don't get an error, just an empty providers list - hmmmm...
- I am initializing the firebase admin instance with `admin.initializeApp()` (e.g. default
  credentials which should come from the project metadata).

---

##### 2022-11-04 UPDATE: appears related to firebase's built-in providers' "type" not being `oidc.*`?

Ok, so I *can* create and list providers with a type of `oidc.*` and
`saml.*` whether I create them with firebase, `auth().createProviderConfig()` or directly with the gcp identity platform console - YAY!

But **I cannot** get the firebase built-in providers (like `google.com`, `twitter.com` etc.) I can only get the ones created with firebase's "custom oidc" provider mechanism.

So the question now becomes **is there any way to get the config associated with one of firebase's built-in providers?**

Comment: Have you enabled the sign-in providers as mentioned in this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541369/18265638)

Comment: yes, they are added just fine. The OP is about listing them in the config results. The UPDATE above is probably the main issue.